# Is there any way to hide the dropdown from a site collection which only contains one language in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, multilingual, sharepoint-online

I am using the multilingualism functionality on a SharePoint online environment. Therefore, I activated this functionality from "Language settings" on the site collection from Site settings. After that, I created a new page and from this one I will generate other translated pages. Everything fine until now.

My question is:
Can I hide the dropdown from the site collection? It will contain only one language. I prefer to do it from SharePoint and not programmatically. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you can't hide it.  But I am puzzled, what are you trying to achieve if you turned on the multilingual page publishing feature, but didn't activate other languages?

Comment: I only want to use the multilingualism functionality on other site pages, but NOT on the site collection homepage (Home.aspx) . This page should be displayes in only one language. Therefore, I don't want to have the dropdown which will contain only one language, it's not really correct, right?  @Martin Laplante

Comment: I see what you mean. Other pages may have several languages, but not this one.

Difficult. I haven't tried this myself. Create a new page library.  You have to create a document library and then add a classic Wiki or Webpart content type. Create a classic page to serve as your home page. Then in the Pages library create a "link" rather than a page, use the URL to the classic page, and make that link the new home page using the right-click menu. You could add the classic content type to the Site Pages library, but that would affect the entire library, allowing anyone to create a classic page.